# How does SQL Server treat MAX of a varchar column?

Tags: sql-server

If I do something like

```
select max(case when col1 = 5 then 'banana' else '0')
```

how will SQL Server choose? What is the maximum value for the column?

Comment: well, have you tried it? executing the script is the quickest way to know what it does..

Comment: Yes, and the text value is selected instead of the '0' text. I am wondering how it chooses the sort order for MAX when the column is text...

Comment: Is there any Group By on this query?

Comment: In the original, yes, but my snippet fully exemplifies what I wanted to know, which is how max treats text values. Now I have learned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that when you do a `MAX(string)` in SQL Server it orders the values alphabetically in an ascending order and picks the last value (bottom of the list)

Can you post the rest of your query? Or explain a bit more one what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: that is most of the query, except 'banana' would be replaced with a varchar column. I did not write it, the person was basically trying to achieve what coalesce does, and it worked, so I was wondering why it worked. I could not find anywhere online that addressed using max with a text column. Thank you.

Comment: Fair enough, the query seems a weird way to use MAX(), hence I was asking for more information.

Answer (score 3):

This is equivalent to taking data that looks like this:

```
col5
1
3
5
7
```

Then converting it to this

```
col5 | case when...
1    | 0
3    | 0
5    | banana
7    | 0
```

Then doing max on the above results. The result falls into four cases:

1. If the data does not contain any rows, then you will get `NULL`.
2. If data only has rows where `col1 = 5` is true, then you will get `banana`.
3. If data only has rows where `col1 = 5` is false, then you will get `0`.
4. If there are both rows where `col1 = 5` is true and false, you will get `banana`, because `banana > 0` according to lexicographical comparison

I have generally only seen this type of query when trying to do the equivalent of PIVOT without using the PIVOT statement.

Comment: Thank you, so it resorts to lexicographical comparison for text. Now I understand.

Comment: +1 well explained.. just for elaboration: since digit precedes letter, it has smaller "value".. that's why `0 < banana`